# Collection Views: Not fitting

Tags: swift, layout, uicollectionview

I have an images that are 182x150 and I set the collection cell to that and made sure it can contain rows of 2 images. But when I run the simulator, the rows only have 1 image. I don't know if it's my code or that I need to resize my image.

```
let itemSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2 - 2

let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 4, bottom: 6, right: 4)
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 4
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 4
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemSize , height: itemSize)

myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

Comment: cell for item size method place width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just need to include section insets in your `itemSize` calculation

```
// 8 for left and right section insets, 4 for item spacing.
let availableWidth = view.bounds.width - 8 - 4
let itemSize = availableWidth / 2
```